# Visual Studio 2013 automatic browser link when html file modified

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

Visual Studio 2013 have feature called [browser link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) but i can't make it automatically refresh browser when i save html file. And if i need to use hotkey of browser link then what is benefit of it? Because i can press F5 in browser instead press hotkey of browser link. But if it refresh automatically when html file is modified then it will be very handy.

So my question is, is it possible to automate browser link when html file is modified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is possible by default.

**And if i need to use hotkey of browser link then what is benefit of it?**

> Browser Link is a new feature that creates a communication channel between the development environment and one or more web browsers. **You can use Browser Link to refresh your web application in several browsers at once**, which is useful for cross-browser testing.

That is refreshing several browsers at once seems to be the main functionality of this feature.

---

To reload a page every time you make a change to it try one of these:

- [Tincr](http://tin.cr/) -  For Chrome.
- [Auto Reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-reload/) - For firefox

Comment: tincr doesn't seem to be very useful on VS2013

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many ways to get browser refresh to work with VS 2013, other IDEs and text editors. In my search I have found the one (in my option) that works best is live-server.
Very easy to install with node nmp 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server 
npm install -g live-server

Here it is on GitHub https://github.com/tapio/live-server